# Laravel issue on migration

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, laravel, migrate

Whenever I make new migrations and trying to migrate it the results I get is this. Even if I try to migrate:refresh and so on. What do you think the problem here? I have also checked my .env file. Thank you!

[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists (SQL: create table `users` (
  `id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) not null,
  `password` varchar(255) not null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` tim
  estamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)

[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.5 Error Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46129270/laravel-5-5-error-base-table-or-view-already-exists-1050-table-users-already)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to create a table that already exists in the database,

Either delete the users table from the database before running `php artisan migrate:refresh`

Or if you have made another migration to add a new column into the users table then you need to have

`Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table)`

Instead of

`Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table)`

It's important to not that `Schema::create` will create the table, and `Schema::table` is what you'd use when modifying an existing table.

Comment: I forgot to include that it is not the "users" table that I want to migrate in the database. But whenever I use php artisan migrate, It does not migrate the new table that I want to include in the database but instead it always give me same results like this one.

Comment: if you run ``php artisan migrate:status`` you can look for the migration file with the (N) next to it that hasn't been migrated. 

In your case when the error is because the table already exists, you could either comment out the lines in the migration file, or if you are adding a new column make sure that you don't have ``Schema::create('tableName', function (Blueprint $table)`` twice.

Answer (score 1):

Use `!Schema::hasTable('users')`, it will check whether a table already exists in the database or not.

If you don't want to drop already exist tables then it is a good idea.

```
if (!Schema::hasTable('users')) {
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```